# CSS Right Column wont stay right

Tags: css

i am trying to set up a right column that wont stay on the right hand side of the page. I would like it to sit up the right hand side of the main content

Here is my Asp.net Code

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Youthpodcast</title>

    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">


    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 873px;
            height: 155px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header"> &nbsp;<div class="title">
            </div>
            <div id="logo"><img alt="" class="style1" src="logo.jpg" /><br /></div>

            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="loginDisplay">



                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                         <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>


            <%--<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">--%>

<%--
    start of the menu--%>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
                    EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    BackColor="#FFFBD6" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                    Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#990000" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px">
                    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
                    <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                    <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" />
                    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About">
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Who are we" Value="Who are we" 
                                NavigateUrl="~/whoarewe.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="What is podcasting" Value="what is podcasting" 
                                NavigateUrl="~/whatispodcasting.aspx">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/listofclubs.aspx" Text="YouthClubs" 
                            Value="YouthClubs"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/contactus.aspx" Text="Contact Us" 
                            Value="Contact Us"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/joinus.aspx" Text="Join" Value="Join">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/admin/adminpage.aspx" Text="Admin" Value="admin">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>
                    <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
                    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                </asp:Menu><%--</asp:UpdatePanel>--%>
              <%--  End of the main navigation menu--%>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                <p>
                    &nbsp;</p>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

           <div id="rightcolumn">


<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F6F3" 
        BorderColor="#E6E2D8" BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
        DisplayRememberMe="False" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" 
        ForeColor="#333333" RememberMeText="" Height="159px" Width="274px">
            <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
            <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
            <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" 
                ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:Login>

       <br />
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
    new TWTR.Widget({
        version: 2,
        type: 'profile',
        rpp: 4,
        interval: 30000,
        width: 250,
        height: 300,
        theme: {
            shell: {
                background: '#57dce6',
                color: '#050505'
            },
            tweets: {
                background: '#4864f0',
                color: '#0a080a',
                links: '#4aed05'
            }
        },
        features: {
            scrollbar: true,
            loop: false,
            live: false,
            behavior: 'all'
        }
    }).render().setUser('YouthPodcast').start();
</script>



    <br /> 


<  </div>
           </div>
        </div>

    </div>




    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And now my CSS see if anyone can find what is causing the problems

```
/* DEFAULTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

body   
{
    background: #b6b7bc;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
    min-width: 500px;
}

#rightcolumn
{

float:right;
width:300px;/*adjust width in px or %. Also adjust #content width.*/
right:-10px;

background:#44B185;
}

a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #034af3;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
    color: #034af3;
}

p
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}


/* HEADINGS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #666666;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* this rule styles <h1> and <h2> tags that are the 
first child of the left and right table columns */
.rightColumn > h1, .rightColumn > h2, .leftColumn > h1, .leftColumn > h2
{
    margin-top: 0px;
}


/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.page
{
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #496077;

}

.header
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: mediumseagreen;
    width: 100%;
}

.header h1
{
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    min-height: 800px;
    width: 10px;
}

.leftCol
{
    padding: 6px 0px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.footer
{
    color: black;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;

}


/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:#3a4f63;
    width:100%;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: Teal;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: HighlightText;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #FF5E00;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* FORM ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

fieldset
{
    margin: 1em 0px;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

fieldset p 
{
    margin: 2px 12px 10px 10px;
}

fieldset.login label, fieldset.register label, fieldset.changePassword label
{
    display: block;
}

fieldset label.inline 
{
    display: inline;
}

legend 
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 2px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input.textEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input.passwordEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.accountInfo
{
    width: 42%;
}

/* MISC  
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.title
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}

.loginDisplay
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    color: White;
}

.loginDisplay a:link
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:visited
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:hover
{
    color: white;
}

.failureNotification
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: Red;
}

.bold
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.submitButton
{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

/*--- Twitter CSS */
#twitter 
{

float: right;
width: 0%;
padding: 250px;
padding-right: 0px;
right: auto;

}

#login
{
float: right;
width: 30;
padding: 1px;  
padding-top: 110px;
    }


/*Contact Us CSS */
#contact-area {
    width: 320px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: Aqua;

}

#contact-area input, #contact-area textarea {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;

}

#contact-area textarea {
    height: 90px;
}

#contact-area textarea:focus, #contact-area input:focus {
    border: 2px solid #900;
}

#contact-area input.submit-button {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

label {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

#address
{
float:right ;
}

#logo
{ position:relative;
right:-40px;
top:-17px;
width:300px;
}

#ticker {  
  width:180px; height:300px; overflow:auto; border:1px solid #aaaaaa;  
}  
#ticker dt {  
  font:normal 14px Georgia; padding:0 10px 5px 10px;  
  background-color:#e5e5e5; padding-top:10px; border:1px solid #ffffff;  
  border-bottom:none; border-right:none;  
}  
#ticker dd {  
  margin-left:0; font:normal 11px Verdana; padding:0 10px 10px 10px;  
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaaaaa; background-color:#e5e5e5;  
  border-left:1px solid #ffffff;  
}  
#ticker dd.last { border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;  
}
/*Round conners news*/

.news  
{
position:absolute;
width:200;
padding:1px;
border:3px solid gray;
margin:0px;
background-color: #B0C4DE;
text-transform:inherit;

}
```

Comment: Please paste HTML code instead of ASP to let us use it for testing next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `float:left` for both left and right column.

Answer (score 0):

```
</script>



    <br /> 


<  </div>
           </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

i think you may have added 1 extra bracket when not needed